# Java vs C# - AddActionListener vs event subscription

Tags: c#, java

Very simple question from one somewhat new to Java: when adding an event handler (or whatever it is called in Java) to a Control, MUST it be an object? I mean, in C# I can do

```
control.event += System.eventHandler(methodThatHandlesEvent)
```

Sure, that's because we have delegate types in C#, but I was wondering if I can choose which method would be called when an event is raised in Java? I mean, in Java I can have something like:

```
control.AddActionListener(objectWhichClassImplementsActionListener)
```

And then I have the `actionPerformed` method in this class, which is the only method that is called. I know there are more kinds of listeners, but I can't have a "ActionListenerHandler" class in which I implement several `actionPerformed` methods that can be assigned to different controls?

Comment: If you're moving from C# to Java and you're already bitter about just the event handlers, maybe you should take a long lunch and start looking around for a new job because it's only going to get more frustrating - hope you weren't too attached to yield return, LINQ, lambdas, delegates, etc!

Comment: ActionListner are everything but "stupid" as you said. C# event make non-sense in OOP and since you talk about C# and JAVA two OOP language you should be glad that Java framework have a interface that allow you to make a class which will encapsulate the treatment of the an action.

Comment: In Java `AddActionListener` transforms to `addActionListener`)

Comment: @Mark Sowul - you're right, the OP is bitter and argumentative.... downvoted

Comment: @S.O. - You may be interested in [the Java language team's view of C# delegates](http://java.sun.com/docs/white/delegates.html) (pretty old, though...)

Comment: Jean, events are basically the same thing as actionListeners except with one method and without you having to write the boilerplate yourself over and over (particularly when writing an object that has events).

Comment: @Mark'sOriginalPost Um... didn't C# lack many of those features for a good while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has no "method pointers", or function types or something like that, so you have to use the [`ActionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface with its `actionPerformed` method, yes. In most cases I give an object of an anonymous class there, which only calls the method which is handling it:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       myRealMethod();
    }
});
```

This is a bit verbose compared to the C# version, but Java has never been a language to save code lines.

---

If you want to have it a bit shorter, you can use [reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html) to help.

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * An adapter class for calling an (almost) arbitrary
 * method as an ActionListener.
 *<p>
 * In fact, you can use any public method which has either no parameter
 * or any parameter of type {@link ActionEvent} or some superclass
 * of it (then it gets passed the ActionEvent there).
 *</p>
 * <p>
 * Additionally, the adapter needs an object of a class containing
 * this method as the receiver.
 * </p>
 *<p>
 * Inspired by the question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182558/java-vs-c-addactionlistener-vs-event-subscription">Java vs C# - AddActionListener vs event subscription</a> on Stackoverflow.
 *</p>
 * @author Paŭlo Ebermann
 */
public class MethodAdapter implements ActionListener {

    /** the receiver object.  */
    private Object target;
    /** the method to be invoked. */
    private Method method;
    /** true if the method accepts the ActionEvent argument,
        false if it is a no-arg method. */
    private boolean takesArgument;

    /**
     * creates a new MethodAdapter.
     * @param o the receiver object.
     * @param mName the name of a method on the receiver.
     *     If there are multiple same-named methods in the class
     *     of the receiver, we take the first one of these: <ul>
     *  <li> a public method taking an ActionEvent as parameter</li>
     *  <li> a public method taking an AWTEvent as parameter</li>
     *  <li> a public method taking an EventObject as parameter</li>
     *  <li> a public method taking an Object as parameter</li>
     *  <li> a public method taking no parameter.</li>
     * </ul>
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if there is no such method.
     */
    public MethodAdapter(Object o, String mName) {
        this(o, findMethod(o, mName));
    }

    /**
     * creates a new MethodAdapter.
     * @param o the receiver object.
     * @param m the method to be invoked.
     *   This method has to be declared in the class of the receiver object
     *   or some supertype, has to take no or one argument, and if one, then
     *   of some supertype of {@link ActionEvent}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the method does not fit the
     *   receiver, if the method takes too much arguments or arguments of
     *   wrong types.
     */
    public MethodAdapter(Object o, Method m) {
        Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
        if(!m.getDeclaringClass().isInstance(o)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong target object");
        }
        if(params.length > 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("too many arguments");
        }
        if(params.length == 1 &&
           ! params[0].isAssignableFrom(ActionEvent.class)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("method not compatible: " + m);
        }
        this.target = o;
        this.method = m;
        this.takesArgument = params.length > 0;
    }

    private static Method findMethod(Object o, String mName) {
        Class<?> c = o.getClass();
        Class<?> eventClass = ActionEvent.class;
        while(eventClass != null) {
            try {
                return c.getMethod(mName, ActionEvent.class);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {}
            eventClass = eventClass.getSuperclass();
        }
        try {
            // try a no-argument method
            return c.getMethod(mName);
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No fitting method named '" +
                                               mName +"' on this object " + o +
                                               " of class " + c.getName());
        }
    }

    /**
     * the implementation of the actionPerformed method.
     * We delegate to our target object and method.
     * Any return value of
     * the method is silently ignored.
     * @throws RuntimeException if any exception is thrown by the invoked
     *   method (or during the invoke process), it is wrapped in a
     *   RuntimeException and rethrown. 
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            if(takesArgument) {
                method.invoke(target, event);
            }
            else {
                method.invoke(target);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof InvocationTargetException) {
                Throwable t = e.getCause();
                if(t instanceof Error)
                    throw (Error)t;
                e = (Exception)t;
            }
            if(e instanceof RuntimeException)
                throw (RuntimeException) e;
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * main method for testing purposes.
     */
    public static void main(String[] params) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        JButton b = new JButton("close");
        b.addActionListener(new MethodAdapter(f, "dispose"));
        f.getContentPane().add(b);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Having this class, you can write

```
button.addActionListener(new MethodAdapter(this, "myRealMethod"));
```

instead of the above code, and on the button click the method will be called.
Note that now the compiler can't do any type checks, so it has to be done on runtime (and you should check your System.err for exceptions stack traces - the application will continue to run even if some event listener throws exceptions). It will be a bit slower, too, but for user interaction this should not really matter.

This is now also part of my [github repository](https://github.com/ePaul/stackoverflow-examples/tree/master/src/de/fencing_game/paul/examples).

---

Update: With Java 8, there are method reference expressions (like `this::myRealMethod`). Java still doesn't have function types, so those expressions are only possible where a SAM-interface (single abstract method) is needed, and then are wrapped into a compiler-generated implementation of that interface, which includes the target object reference and an implementation of the interface's method which calls the target method.

Comment: Of course! That would be the best solution, feeling kinda stupid myself for not thinking that.

Comment: @djaqeel: I didn't intend to insult Java (after all, this is the language I'm using most). Which of my phrases did you interpret as insulting? (The "*stupid `actionPerformed` method*" was a quote from the original question.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann So nice off you, you came back and clarified... The OP has removed "stupid" word, you should also remove that word. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @djaqeel I removed the "stupid" (which is a quite mild insult, when not directed at a person, I think), and also added some links. (Actually, not S.O. (the asker) removed "stupid", but berry120 (the latest editor of the question).)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Thankyou very much. Its not a mild insult, its too much for such an honourable, elder sister of many languages if not mother. And probably I am doing the same thing as berry120 did with the question, but I do not have the editing privileges. Any ways so nice off you.

Answer (score 1):

> MUST it be an object?

In Java all should be an *Object)*
You can declare your *listeners* as you want with any number of methods with any number of parameters, but *Observable* object should know what method call and what arguments pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous inner class to avoid having the `ActionListener` declared separately and cluttering up your project with unnecessary helper classes:

```
control.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Button clicked.");
    }
});
```

Note the `new ActionListener() { ... }`, which is declaring an anonymous class which implements `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that will encapsulate sub-classes like

```
public class MyEvents
{
   public class MyEvent_1 : ActionListner
   {
    ....
   }
   public class MyEvent_2 : ActionListner
   {
    ....
   }
}
```

this way all your event will be at the same place as you want.